# GCE startup script fails to run on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gsutil

I am launching an instance on GCP using `gcloud compute` and specifying the URL of my script using the metadata param. The script fails to run, when I check the metadata, the script url is there. The logs have no mention of any errors.

When I `sudo -i` and copy the script down from the bucket and execute, it runs fine.

Instance is running Ubuntu 18.04. Any ideas?

Comment: just tested this with a fresh instance, ubuntu 18.04 and a simple script that just makes a dir and also it didn't run. must be a bug. works fine with ubuntu 16.04. where can i file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the issue you are facing is related to a Google Known issue with the new Image Ubuntu 18.04.

In particular after the update of the image `gsutil` is not available during the startup, therefore you will be not able to download it and it will fail.

I advice you to check the public issue, and to star it to follow and receive the updates:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/78907347

Comment: If you don't want to wait for the fix, the debian image doesn't have this problem.

Comment: seems like the problem is a lot more than "gsutil not available on startup". `gsutil --version` returns with `ImportError: No module named google_compute_engine` even after boot